# find is checkbox checked?

Tags: jquery, primefaces

How do I find if p:selectBooleanCheckbox is checked?

The jquery script below always return false or undefined for p:selectBooleanCheckbox but it works as expected for h:selectBooleanCheckbox

```
<h:form id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="mycbx" value="#{mybean.cbxSelect}" />
</h:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myform\\:mycbx').click(function () {
    console.log($(this).is(':checked')); //always return false!
    console.log($(this).prop('checked')); //return undefined
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

for primefaces component use widgetVar:

```
<h:form id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="mycbx" widgetVar="cbx" value="#{mybean.cbxSelect}" />
</h:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myform\\:mycbx').click(function () {
console.log(cbx.isChecked()); //return true if check
});
```

nice intro to widgetVar: http://blog.hatemalimam.com/intro-to-primefaces-widgetvar/

Comment: Keep mind that using `cbx.isChecked()` uses the old way of accessing functions on widgets. More recent versions of PF require you to use `PF('cbx').isChecked()` unless the compatibility option is set